# Error 403: Permission iam.serviceAccounts.create is required to perform this operation on project projects/, forbidden

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to create GKE cluster from terraform. I have an existing service account and I don't want to create any new service account instead use the one which I have.

I am getting error while running my terraform script, can you please suggest.

I am referring to this link here:
https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/kubernetes-engine/google/latest

```
provider "google" {
  credentials =file("xxx.json")
  project     = "myproject"
  region      = "us-east1"
}


module "gke" {
  source                     = "terraform-google-modules/kubernetes-engine/google"
  project_id                 = "myproject_id"
  name                       = "gke-test-2"
  region                     = "us-east1-c"
  zones                      = ["us-east1-b","us-east1-d"]
  network                    = "VPC"
  subnetwork                 = "VPC_SUBNET"
  ip_range_pods              = "us-east-1-subnet1"
  ip_range_services          = "us-east-1-subnet2"
  http_load_balancing        = false
  network_policy             = false
  horizontal_pod_autoscaling = true
  filestore_csi_driver       = false

  node_pools = [
    {
      name                      = "default-node-pool"
      machine_type              = "e2-medium"
      min_count                 = 1
      max_count                 = 2
      local_ssd_count           = 0
      disk_size_gb              = 100
      disk_type                 = "pd-standard"
      image_type                = "COS_CONTAINERD"
      auto_repair               = true
      auto_upgrade              = true
      service_account           = "XXXXX@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      preemptible               = false
      initial_node_count        = 2
    },
  ]

  node_pools_oauth_scopes = {
    all = []

    default-node-pool = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    ]
  }

  node_pools_labels = {
    all = {}

  }

  node_pools_metadata = {
    all = {}

    default-node-pool = {
      node-pool-metadata-custom-value = "my-node-pool"
    }
  }

  node_pools_taints = {
    all = []

  }

  node_pools_tags = {
    all = []

  }
}
```

Comment: Is this your existing service account "XXXXX@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com" which is mentioned in node pools? The create_service_account variable default value (true) will cause a cluster-specific service account to be created. By default create_service_account field will be true which created cluster-specific service account, so try setting the value of the field “create_service_account” to **false**. Refer to the service_account field description under [inputs](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/kubernetes-engine/google/latest#inputs) for more information.

Comment: I tried with this but no help

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the role **Create Service Accounts** (`iam.serviceAccounts.create`) to your service account to create service accounts when creating the cluster.

Or else you can assign the **Service account Admin** role to the existing service account.

Comment: as per org policy we cannot give create service account role to service account. Is there is any other way to do this?
using same service account when i tried to create cluster in UI , it works but while using terraform i am getting this error.

Comment: that's weird let me try it once and update you back.if it's working from ui thn ideally it should work with TF also